# Variable to store in the extracted fonts

Tags: vba, variables

```
Sub TextFonts()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim sFontName As String


With ActivePresentation
    For Each oSl In .Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            With oSh
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                       .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = sFontName

                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

I am stuck at sFontName. And I want to store the number of occurrences in array to keep a count of each font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting ... you found a nasty bug in VBA/PowerPoint. This line totally crashes the program:

```
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = sFontName
```

It should be this:

```
sFontName =.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
```

As to storing the info, try it this way. You'll end up with an array of strings like:
FontName|X
where X is the current count.
The AddFontToArray sub has code you can use to unpack each string into fontname and count.

For another challenge, consider what happens when a single text box in PPT has multiple fonts. As it stands, the code will pick up only the fontname of the first character in the text box. If you want to get fancy, use .Runs to get each run of text. Every change to font or font formatting is a new run.

```
Sub TextFonts()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim sFontName As String

Dim x As Long
Dim aFonts() As String
ReDim aFonts(1 To 1)

With ActivePresentation
    For Each oSl In .Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            With oSh
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                       sFontName = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
                        AddFontToArray aFonts, sFontName
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
End With

For x = LBound(aFonts) + 1 To UBound(aFonts)
    Debug.Print aFonts(x)
Next

End Sub

Sub AddFontToArray(aFonts As Variant, sFontName As String)

    Dim x As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim sName As String

    ' each entry in the array looks like FONTNAME|X where X is the current count

    ' is the font name there already?
    For x = LBound(aFonts) To UBound(aFonts)
        ' is anything in this array element?
        If Len(aFonts(x)) > 0 Then
            sName = Mid$(aFonts(x), 1, InStr(aFonts(x), "|") - 1)
            If sName = sFontName Then   ' it's there/get the count
                lCount = CLng(Mid$(aFonts(x), InStr(aFonts(x), "|") + 1))
                'increment the count
                lCount = lCount + 1
                'and put it back into the array
                aFonts(x) = sName & "|" & CStr(lCount)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' If we got here, the font's not in the array yet
    ' Add another array element to hold it
    ReDim Preserve aFonts(LBound(aFonts) To UBound(aFonts) + 1)
    ' and add it to the array
    aFonts(UBound(aFonts)) = sFontName & "|" & "1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. I cannot believe changing equality made such a huge difference.

Comment: While it shouldn't just crash (and may not in later versions than I tested with), it does make sense that PPT wouldn't allow "" as a font name, which is what the original version of your code was doing.

Comment: FWIW, checked this same bug in O365 and PPT 2016. In the former, it sets the font name to blank. In the latter, PPT reports that the font is now +Body Asian. Neither makes a great deal of sense, but at least it doesn't crash.